# Footstepper with Vr Unity

Tags: unity, assets, virtual-reality

I have the Footstepper: Complete Footstep Solution from the unity store, and i dont get it working with the Vr,

I made the footstep material like official documentation said, Then
i put the Footstepper Setup in the ovrPlayer object.

The problem is that sometimes sound the default fallback, so i think that the colission is not detected as it suppose.

Some idea ?

Comment: We would need a minimum running example - basically new scene with the least amount of setup that can reproduce the error - to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, i dont have it with me now, but basically i have the ovrPlayer object from the vr oficcial asset and the footsteper setted in there with the autoplay true, then i have a object atachhed with the Object Footstep Source and inside a footstepper material defined, maybe could be that i miss a Trigger Footstep Source or edit the Raycast Settings of the ovr player, i dont have the Pc now, monday i update the question even if i get the awnser :)

Answer (score 0):

Effectively i change the Raycast Settings to get more height and it works :)

Comment: This answer would be even better if it showed how you did that, so future users with the same problem can follow in your footsteps, as it were. 